# how can I create wifi hotspot on windows 7 that can be shared with my macbook?

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, windows, internet-sharing

My USB modem has issues so my Mac doesn't recognize it. I created an ad hoc wifi hotspot  on my Windows 7 laptop with WPA2 encryption and shared the internet. My Macbook Pro sees the wireless network but when I enter the password I get a connection failed warning. I tried connecting also with my iPhone and before I entered the password I got a messag/e that "MyWirelessNetwork" is not connected to the internet. How can I solve this issue

Comment: Does it work if you set up sharing with WEP (just for testing)?

Comment: no, the issue is the same

Comment: bmike's answer looked good.  Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to run the Wireless Diagnostic from the Mac since it's easy. There are iOS diagnostics, but you'll have the best luck determining why OS X won't connect to the network. From there, the iPhone issue will likely be solved, but if not you'll have a smaller problem to solve.

Option click your WiFi icon in the menu bar (place it there in network settings if it's absent) and then select Wireless Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

yeah sure you can,read the tutorial below, it exactly helps you out
http://www.techtweetz.com/how-to-create-wifi-hotspot-on-windows-7-8-1-10/

Comment: what part of that will help someone that's already created a hotspot but can't get it to integrate with their iPhone?